# Regex matching character preceded by a pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, python-3.x

Given the following setting:

- **input** = `"window.addEventListener('click', (s, d) => {});"`
- **desired match** = `"(s, d) =>"`

tried the regex

```
(.*).*=>
```

But this will match `"('click', (s, d) =>"`, which is not desired.

Any ideas on how to modify the regex so that the match only starts from the closest opening parentheses before the `"=>"` symbol?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex with `re.findall`:

```
>>> s = "window.addEventListener('click', (s, d) => {});"
>>> print (re.findall(r'\([^()]*\)\s*=>', s)[0])
(s, d) =>
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `\(`: Match `(`
- `[^()]*`: Match 0 or more of any character that is not `(` and `)`
- `\)`: Match `)`
- `\s*=>`: Match 0 or more whitespaces followed by text `=>`

Answer (score 1):

this is what you need to use. lookbehind more precisely 
https://javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind

Answer (score 1):

`(?<=\().+(\(.+\).*=>)`

See [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/6m7R09/1)

Basically a lookbehind for the first open paren, and a capture group for the desired result.